# Static resources are not being served

Tags: spring-mvc

I want to serve static resources in my **spring web MVC application**. In this project, I am using annotation based configuration, but static resources are not getting served. I tried from both side:

**1st way**

```
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {

registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/WEB-INF/resources/");
}
```

**2nd way**

```
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use SpringBoot default configuration you can access static resource from default web route. For example http://yourhost:8080/images/test.jpg where images is a a folder in the static branch.

Comment: I am using spring core and when I add @Override annotation eclipse telling me to remove that annotation